# How do I pass url parameter to form value?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, forms

The form has this hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="dir_type" value="tshirt">
```

url parameters are

```
/dir?type=tshirt
/dir?type=books
/dir?type=posters
```

and so on.

Now I hard coded `value="tshirts"` but how do I get parameter for the relevant page?

I found several pages [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032534/how-to-pass-the-end-of-the-url-to-a-value-in-a-form) dealing with similar topics but I did not understand how this is done.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

The [answer by systempuntoout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769063/how-do-i-pass-url-parameter-to-form-value/4770192#4770192) works perfectly but I decided to solve the problem without using templates. And for anyone who has a similar question, passing the url parameter to the form like this works well:

```
<form name="submit_form" action="/directorysubmithandler" method="post" onSubmit="return validate_form()">
title: <input type="text" name="title" size=50><br />
url: <input type="text" name="url" size=50><br />
<input type="hidden" name="dir_type" value="%s")>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>""" % self.request.get("type"))
```

Comment: Is it so that you want to set value of hidden form field depends on URL? If yes, you might use javascript to parse location.href and set form field value. But I think that it is better to generate correct html on server side that will include value for hidden field.

Comment: @Stipa: "But I think that it is better to generate correct html on server side that will include value for hidden field." How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What platform do you have on server side? How to you server html pages?

Comment: @Stipa: I am using Google App Engine with Python. html pages are in a folder and in the configuration file I indicate which directory.

Comment: You have to make page dynamically served. Next you may check this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html

Comment: @Stipa: Yes, I am serving the page dynamically and I know how to get the form value from the form. But in this case I need to use the url parameter saved in the Directory handler in the DirectorySubmitHandler. Python would not let me use a variable saved in one class in another class. So I don't know what to put in the value field in the form in Directory to pass the url parameter to DirectorySubmitHandler.

Comment: more info here http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/62738fb02ee228f7?hl=en#

Comment: Why don't you want to use templates? They'll make your life a _lot_ easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a.** pass the `type` value to the view:

```
class Directory(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       ....
       merchandise_type = self.request.get("type", "")
       items = Item.all()
       items.filter("type =", merchandise_type)
       path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dir_details.html')
       self.response.out.write(template.render(path,{'type':merchandise_type}))
```

**b.** add the `type` value to the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dir_type" value="{{ type }}">
```

**c.** get the `dir_type` value in your post handler:

```
class DirectorySubmitHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        merchandise_type = self.request.get("dir_type", "")
        dir_type = merchandise_type
        if user:
            item = Item()
            item.title = self.request.get("title")
            item.url = self.request.get("url")
            item.type = self.request.get("dir_type")
            item.user_who_liked_this_item = user
            item.put()
            self.redirect("/dir?type=%s" %
self.request.get("dir_type"))
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

Comment: @systempuntoout: I am not using templates. If I add "type" to the form value obviously it redirects to /dir?type=type. This is what I don't understand. How to do this without templates?

Comment: Without templates, you have to do it via Javascript, as in the question you linked to.

Comment: @Spacedman: Maybe I am not understanding this but I have no problem getting the url parameter (as that javascript does). I want to use the url parameter saved in Directory handler in the DirectorySubmitHandler. Python gives global name not defined error if I try to use a variable defined in one class in another class. Thanks.

Comment: @systempuntoout: Thanks for this answer. I created a new handler to do this with templates but so far I am not having any luck; template prints as text. I am trying to figure out how to fix that. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @Zeynel ask another question or modify this one with your code

Comment: @systempuntoout: Ok, I added an update with a solution without using templates. I realized that using {{ type }} in template is equivalent for using string formatting in the script. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: @Spacedman There's absolutely no connection between the use of templates and Javascript. He can do it server-side just fine, with or without templates.