# Best way to redirect to referring page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, referrer

I have a question similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769063/how-do-i-pass-url-parameter-to-form-value).

In the same app I have the `VoteHandler` that adds +1 when users click on the up arrow and then redirects to the same page.

Now that I added the url parameters to the pages and urls look like this

```
/dir?type=tshirt
```

I need to be able to redirect to the correct page.

And as mentioned [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/e26408fa368f6abb?hl=en) by Nick Johnson `referrer` is not a good way of redirecting.

I would appreciate help about how to fix `VoteHandler` so that it redirects to the correct page.

Thanks!

```
class VoteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        id = int(id)
        item = Item.get_by_id(id)

        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            greeting = ("%s (<a href='%s'>sign out</a>)" %
                           (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)))

            #--check if user voted on this item before--#
            query  = SiteUser.all()
            query.filter("liked_items =", (str(item.key().id())))
            already_voted = query.get()

            if already_voted:
                self.redirect("/onevote")
            else:
                query = SiteUser.all()          
                query.filter("site_user =", users.get_current_user())

                data = query.get()

                data.total_votes += 1
                data.liked_items = str(item.key().id())
                data.site_user = users.get_current_user()

                db.put(data)

                item.points += 1
                item.put()            

                if self.request.referrer == 'http://localhost:8083//newest':
                    self.redirect('/newest')
                elif self.request.referrer == 'http://localhost:8083/hot':
                    self.redirect('/hot')
                #How do I fix this line to get the correct url parameter?
                elif self.request.referrer == 'http://localhost:8083/dir?type=tshirt':
                    self.redirect('/dir/tshirt')    
                else:     
                    self.redirect("/")                       
        else:            
            greeting = ("<a href='%s'>Sign in with your Google account or register</a>." %
                           cgi.escape(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)))
```

**UPDATE**

The [answer by systempuntoout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775906/best-way-to-redirect-to-referring-page/4776748#4776748) works great but I had to change the vote link in `Directory` from

```
/vote/%s
```

to

```
/vote/%s?type=%s
```

so that I could get the `merchandise_type` in `VoteHandler`:

```
self.response.out.write("<ol>")
for item in items:
    self.response.out.write("""<li>
                                   <a href="/vote/%s?type=%s"> ^ </a><a href="%s">%s</a> <span id='Small'>(%s)</span><br /> 
                                   <div id='Small'> 
                                     %s points %s by %s <a href="/item/%s"></a> | 
                                     <a href="/item/%s#disqus_thread"></a>
                                   </div>
                               </li><br /> """ % 
                                    (str(item.key().id()), merchandise_type, item.url, item.title, urlparse(item.url).netloc,
                                    item.points, item.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p"), item.user_who_liked_this_item, str(item.key().id()), str(item.key().id())))                               

self.response.out.write("</ol>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `type` parameter in this way:

```
class VoteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        id = int(id)
        item = Item.get_by_id(id)
        merchandise_type = self.request.get("type", "")
        ..
        self.redirect('/%s' % merchandise_type)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works great. But I had to add the `merchandise_type` to vote link in the `Directory` handler otherwise I couldn't get the type in the `VoteHandler`. I put an update for the record. Thanks again.